# Can I power a separate cooktop and wall oven from a single circuit?

Tags: electrical, appliances, 240v

I am replacing my 240V electric cooking range with a glass cooktop (with 4 heating plates) and a separate wall oven.  The old cooking range was a plug-in.  The two new appliances (the glass cooktop and wall oven) are meant to be hard wired (not plug-ins).  Can both new appliances be hard wired into the single circuit that was being used for the old cooking range?

Comment: The answer is 99% no, but it can't be answered without knowing the size of the circuit and the max load of the appliances.

Comment: @Faro -- what electrical code is in force where you live?  The US NEC has provisions for this situation...but a foreign electrical code may do things differently!

Answer (score 1):

Any cooktop and separate oven I had put into the houses I helped build, required a separate circuit for each.

Comment: Then what's Note 4 on Table 220.55 used for?  I seriously doubt the NEC authors would leave a superfluous provision hanging around the Code for several cycles of codemaking...or was the requirement you ran into a local code issue?